# PageView vs. TabBarView

Tags: flutter

I made a simple app and have an issue when using PageView vs. TabBarView. Both show 3 stateless widgets and the first widget has the FutureBuilder inside. When using PageView and navigating away from the first widget loading async data is invoked. That is not really what I expect.On the other side, with TabBarView loading async data does not take place when navigating away from the first screen.Can someone explain why is that?Of course I can use initState method to load the data and then use it in widget's build method but then what is the purpose of FutureBuilder?

Here is my sample app: https://gist.github.com/SekibOmazic/ddfe8281357a9d0a9df1ad192a36a393 in case you want to see the code